# I'm trying to make a simple Discord Bot, but it doesn't work

Tags: java, discord, bots, minecraft, discord-jda

I'm trying to make a simple Discord Bot within a Minecraft Mod, and it doesn't work. I do have to say that I am new to coding discord bots in java, as I am more based to javascript.

Here is what I made:

DiscordBot.java

```
public class DiscordBot
{
    public JDA jda;
    
    private String token = "----";
    
    public static DiscordBot instance = new DiscordBot();
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void startDiscordBot() throws LoginException
    {
        jda = new JDABuilder()
                .setToken(token)
                .setStatus(OnlineStatus.DO_NOT_DISTURB)
                .addEventListeners(new DiscordEventListener())
                .build();
    }
}
```

DiscordEventListener.java

```
public class DiscordEventListener extends ListenerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event)
    {   
        if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("-login"))
        {
            EmbedBuilder eb1 = new EmbedBuilder();
            EmbedBuilder eb2 = new EmbedBuilder();
            
            event.getAuthor().openPrivateChannel().queue(channel -> {
                eb2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                eb2.setTitle(placeholder-text);
                eb2.setDescription(placeholder-text);
                channel.sendMessage(eb2.build());
            });
```

The DiscordEventListener takes "-login" and responds with the rest of the code, but the problem is, while the bot does go online, it doesn't do anything when I send -login in the discord server, nor dms. Also no errors occur on launch neither on the event. Also, I have a depricated version of JDA (4.2.1) because I don't understand how to use the new one.

I tried multiple little things but they showed 0 results, so I don't know what is wrong here.

(Also yes, I have initialised the DiscordBot class in the Main one, so I don't think that is the problem)

Comment: You should not use `new JDABuilder()` but `JDABuilder.createDefault()` or similar.

Comment: @dan1st I tried what you said, but still no difference. the bot goes online, but doesn't do anything when i type -login

Comment: You forgot the `.queue()`: `channel.sendMessage(eb2.build()).queue();`

Comment: @dan1st thank you, it works now! but i have another problem; i don't want to prolong the disscusion here so if you could add me on discord (LucaForever#6969) to help me, it would be much apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dan1st figured it out, I forgot to add `.queue();` to the end of `channel.sendMessage`, so thanks to them.